# Modify globals() in context manager and make use of it in another file

Tags: python, oop, dynamic-programming

Following is the code trying to modify `globals()`. It works well in the script.

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

    def __enter__(self):
        globals()['w'] = self.v

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

with C(1) as c:
    print(w)   # OK, here
```

However, when I import it into other files, it fails. Is it possible to grasp the variables in `globals()` updated in the imported modules? (Never try to use import-statement `from . import w`)

```
# in another file
# import statement

with C(1) as c:
    print(w)   # Error
```

Comment: `global` variables only have the scope of the file, when you run this it will apparently go back to the file you imported it from and run it there and make the global variable there

Comment: I feel like this question is possible an example of the XY problem. Could you maybe give us an example use case, or explain what the purpose of this code is? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: @AlexWaygood I just want modify the globals() with `with-statements` in a silent way, then other statements in `with-scope` can make use of variables in globals(). For example: with LetterAsVariable(): ... then I can use x, y, z as variables without assigning them explicitly. Thank you for paying attention to my strange idea~

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I fully understand the purpose or intent  of your code, but here are two alternative approaches that may demonstrate some different solutions to your problem. Both examples are in the interactive REPL.

**Option 1: return `self` in `__enter__`**

```
>>> class C:
...   def __init__(self, x, y, z):
...     self.x = x
...     self.y = y
...     self.z = z
...   def __enter__(self):
...     return self
...   def __exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
...     pass
...     
>>> with C(1, 2, 3) as c:
...    a, b, c = c.x, c.y, c.z
...    print(a)
...    print(b)
...    print(c)
...    
1
2
3
```

**Option 2: return attributes of the context manager in `__enter__`**

```
>>> class C:
...   def __init__(self, x, y, z):
...     self.x = x
...     self.y = y
...     self.z = z
...   def __enter__(self):
...     return self.x, self.y, self.z
...   def __exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
...     pass
...     
>>> with C(1, 2, 3) as (a, b, c):
...    print(a)
...    print(b)
...    print(c)
...    
1
2
3
```

**Option 1** is a more common pattern, since **Option 2** does not in fact preserve a reference to the context-manager instance that is controlling the operation of the `with` statement. Depending on what you're using the context manager for, this may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you anyway. Option 1 is sensible, though it dose not solve my question.